# nginx redirect issue with upstream configuration

Tags: nginx, perl

I have a website running with nginx and Plack/Starman as upstream. simple configuration looks like:

```
upstream findmjob {
    server unix:/tmp/findmjob.sock;
}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name findmjob.com www.findmjob.com fb.findmjob.com;

  access_log /findmjob.com/log/access.log;
  error_log  /findmjob.com/log/error.log info;

  root /findmjob.com/static;
  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location @proxy {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass       http://findmjob;
  }
}
```

I have some perl code which returns a redirect. it means it works fine under perl/plack:

```
Faylands-MacbookPro:findmjob.com fayland$ curl -I 'http://findmjob.com:5000/job/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw/'
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 06:14:38 GMT
Server: HTTP::Server::PSGI
Location: http://findmjob.com/freelance/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw
Server: Perl Dancer 1.3095
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.3095
```

as you see it's really with 'http://findmjob.com/'.

but when I use the socks and nginx, it returns something like:

```
Faylands-MacbookPro:findmjob.com fayland$ curl -I 'http://findmjob.com/job/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw/'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 06:15:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: .com/freelance/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw
Content-Length: 0
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.3095
```

the http://findmjob is dropped, only .com is left?!

any help is really appreciated.

Updated: upgrade to the latest version fixed it.

```
Faylands-MacbookPro:findmjob.com fayland$ curl -I 'http://findmjob.com/job/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw/'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.0
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 08:22:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://findmjob.com/freelance/GK3bmm+P4RG+2MTa2fVHmw
X-Powered-By: Perl Dancer 1.3095
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your upstream defined as 'http://findjob' and default for `proxy_redirect` is

```
proxy_redirect   http://findjob /;
```

And this means that nginx will strip string equal to first arg to `proxy_redirect` (http://findjob) from proxied `Location:`.

Use `proxy_redirect off;`  instead to fix this issue. Check [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) for details.

Comment: Thanks for it. and weird that I upgraded it to the latest version and it fixes too.

Comment: Well, I think that using upsteam id in this case was a bug in nginx which was worth fixing.